# If 'phrase' in csv column, write a new row saying true/false with Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to sort through some emails. A particular email was sent out and I want to find out who replied. I have two csv files which I have formulated already, one with the email requests, and one with the email replies, both with headers; Subject, To, From, Date.

Unfortunately, the email replies 'From' has the format `(Joe Bloggs <joebloggs@gmail.com>)`, whereas the email requests 'To' has the format of just `(joebloggs@gmail.com)`. So I cannot directly relate them as they are not identical so I'll need to search for the string (the email address)

This is my current code

```
import csv

req=open('DESmailrequests.csv', 'rb')
requests=csv.reader(req)
rep=open('Desmailreplies.csv', 'rb')
replies=csv.reader(rep)

comparison = open('DESmailrequests.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(comparison)

for row in replies:
    replies_2=row[2]
replies_2 = set(replies_2)
```

Hit a bump. Basically I want to be able to say, if `string/phrase` from requests[1] in replies[2], write new row in requests saying 'replied'/'not replied'

```
for row in requests:
    if row[1] in replies_2:
        writer.writerow(row[3])

req.close()
rep.close()
comparison.close()
```

This isn't working so far, I'm just getting a blank csv. I'd appreciate any help possible.

So far, sorting these ~10,000 emails with Python has been an absolute blast and relatively simple! Just hit a bump at the final hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in :

```
comparison = open('DESmailrequests.csv', 'wb')
```

When doing this you are creating a new 'DESmailrequests.csv' **empty** file.
The csv reader is reading an empty file so :

```
for row in requests:
```

result in doing nothing at all.

You should open the file in 'append' mode :

```
comparison = open('DESmailrequests.csv', 'ab')
```

Comment: Ah yes. The output file is actually DESmailcomparison.csv! I forgot to change that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problem I see in your code. The first one, and the cause why you are getting an empty file is:

```
comparison = open('DESmailrequests.csv', 'wb')
```

You are deleting your own file. Why are you not opening a new file? With another name?

Second, you said it yourself, the From lists can't be compared to the Reply to list. So you are trying to compare wrongly a string to a list.

```
In [5]: senders = {"Joe Bloggs <joebloggs@gmail.com>", "Foo Bar <foo.bar@example.com>"} 

In [6]: senders
Out[6]: {'Foo Bar <foo.bar@example.com>', 'Joe Bloggs <joebloggs@gmail.com>'}

In [7]: "Foo Bar" in senders
Out[7]: False
```

Note that this won't work either:

```
In [15]: "<foo.bar@example.com>" in {"Joe Bloggs <joebloggs@gmail.com>", "Foo Bar <foo.bar@example.com>"}
Out[15]: False
```

You need to clean the list of sendres with some regex or python logic before you can do the comparison:

```
In [8]: def extract_mail(str):
   ...:     return str[str.index('<'):str.index('>')+1]
   ...: 

In [9]: map(extract_mail, senders)
Out[9]: ['<joebloggs@gmail.com>', '<foo.bar@example.com>']
```

Now you can do the comparison.

Here is the correct way to extract the emails in way you can compare them:

```
In [18]: def extract_mail(str):                                                                  
    return str [str.index('<')+1:str.index('>')]
   ....: 

In [19]: map(extract_mail, {"Joe Bloggs <joebloggs@gmail.com>", "Foo Bar <foo.bar@example.com>"})
Out[19]: ['joebloggs@gmail.com', 'foo.bar@example.com']
```

So now your search works:

```
In [20]: "joebloggs@gmail.com" in ['joebloggs@gmail.com', 'foo.bar@example.com']
Out[20]: True
```

Comment: Yes, having worked on it for a while yesterday, I was thinking that I should try and clean up the email addresses within the lists! Thank you so much. I will try this and fingers crossed it will work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. It keeps saying that '<' is not in list, but it is in the list, I've checked!!

Comment: Maybe some E-Mails don't have it. In that case you'll probably have to use regex which might be better than my solution  as is.